# UIButton Not Clickable when added UITabbar

Tags: swift, uibutton, uitabbar

When added UIButton on UITabbar to middle as shown in figure.
The button action on above the UITabBar unable to click

```
func setupMiddleButton() {
    plusButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 64, height: 64))
    
    var menuButtonFrame = plusButton.frame
    menuButtonFrame.origin.x = tabBar.bounds.width/2 - menuButtonFrame.size.width/2
    
    let hasNotched :Bool? = UIDevice.current.hasNotch

    if hasNotched != nil {
        menuButtonFrame.origin.y = tabBar.bounds.height - menuButtonFrame.height - 15
    } else {
        menuButtonFrame.origin.y = tabBar.bounds.height - menuButtonFrame.height - 50
    }
    
    plusButton.frame = menuButtonFrame
    plusButton.setTitle("+", for: .normal)
    plusButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.helveticaNeue(ofSize: 40)
    plusButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(hexString: "5E71FE")
    plusButton.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0,left: 10,bottom: 10,right: 10)
    tabBar.addSubview(plusButton)

    plusButton.layer.cornerRadius = menuButtonFrame.height/2
    plusButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(plusButtonAction(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    
}
```

[image]

Comment: It is not clickable as its top section is outside of your UITabBar's frame, or else visible but not user interactable. You will need to move this button outside of the UITabBar

Comment: @Pancho any custom TabBar Controller available to have such behaviour?

Answer (score 6):

You need to override the hitTest method in your custom tab bar class like this

```
override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? 
{
    guard !clipsToBounds && !isHidden && alpha > 0 else { return nil }

    for member in subviews.reversed() 
    {
            let subPoint = member.convert(point, from: self)
            guard let result = member.hitTest(subPoint, with: event) 
            else { continue }
            return result
    }

    return nil
}
```

Basically the problem is that upper part is not clickable because it is outside of the bounds of main content view of tab bar.

This method will check if the tap is inside the bounds of the view, if it is it will return the view and the action for that button will get called.

Documentation by apple: [Link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622469-hittest)

P.s I was facing the same issue recently and got this help which worked smooth.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that what you are trying to do is not possible, or at the least, not supported by Apple. (And thus not recommended since you might find a way to make it might work today but not in some future OS version.)

As a rule, Apple does not support you adding custom view objects to system components like tab bars, navigation bars, stack views, table/collection view controllers, etc except through a documented API.

I would suggest NOT doing what you are trying to do. instead, add a button in the content view of the tab bar controller. I don't know if you'll be able to make it partly cover the tab bar like you are trying to do however.

Answer (score 0):

Add the button to the view of the UITabbarController instead of adding to the TabBar. And then reposition the button, it will work.